# What's the best way to clean marbonite tiles

Tags: tile, floor, cleaning, spraypainting

I have installed the white marbonite tiles floor tiles which is quite shiny or reflective.

Recently painters used spray gun to make the door frames, doors shiny but as a result of that the tiles surrounding this place has become bit dull.

How can I bring back the actual glossiness of tiles by cleaning and not affecting the tile.

I tried regular [floor / tiles surface cleaner](https://www.amazon.in/Lizol-Disinfectant-Floor-Cleaner-Floral/dp/B00NWFY6GE) but it was not helpful.

Any ideas what I can do ?

Comment: You need something that dissolves paint. Not safe but working is to use a towel and gasoline. Make sure the room is well vented.

Comment: @Ruskes - I will try that. The paint is so invisible we just assume that there might be a invisible film on top of tiles that has made the tile not glossy.

Comment: I just wonder how long the floor will hold the smell of gasoline. Wouldn't like to experiment to find out. You can get specialist marbonite cleaners. I'd also be wondering why the painters took no pains to cover their potential overspill surfaces. You might be asking them to fix this, at their cost.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thanks. I will reach out to specialists but I thought I'd try some DIY